# How can i edit whmcs template navigation bar?

Tags: php, whmcs

I want to edit items into navigation bar provided into `whmcs` template. How can I edit that can anybody give some idea about that?

below is site image.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ytq4hxF0jXYCtc3_lbUEVlVxKPX8pb21/view?usp=sharing

I am modifying `whmcs` template for my company project. website using PHP, Html, CSS and some of the JavaScript code. I have modified some of the pages into that also changed URLs for navbar items. But I am not able to add or remove items into the navbar.

Navbar comes from below code.

`{foreach $navbar as $item}
    <li menuItemName="{$item->getName()}" class="{if $item->hasChildren()}dropdown{/if}{if $item->getClass()} {$item->getClass()}{/if}" id="{$item->getId()}">
        <a {if $item->hasChildren()}class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"{else}href="{$item->getUri()}"{/if}{if $item->getAttribute('target')} target="{$item->getAttribute('target')}"{/if}>
            {if $item->hasIcon()}<i class="{$item->getIcon()}"></i>&nbsp;{/if}
            {$item->getLabel()}
            {if $item->hasBadge()}&nbsp;<span class="badge">{$item->getBadge()}</span>{/if}
            {if $item->hasChildren()}&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b>{/if}
        </a>
        {if $item->hasChildren()}
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {foreach $item->getChildren() as $childItem}
                <li menuItemName="{$childItem->getName()}"{if $childItem->getClass()} class="{$childItem->getClass()}"{/if} id="{$childItem->getId()}">
                    <a href="{$childItem->getUri()}"{if $childItem->getAttribute('target')} target="{$childItem->getAttribute('target')}"{/if}>
                        {if $childItem->hasIcon()}<i class="{$childItem->getIcon()}"></i>&nbsp;{/if}
                        {$childItem->getLabel()}
                        {if $childItem->hasBadge()}&nbsp;<span class="badge">{$childItem->getBadge()}</span>{/if}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {/foreach}
            </ul>
        {/if}
    </li>
{/foreach}`

Answer (score 2):

WHMCS generate menus automatically, you must create a hook to change the menus; see hook: [ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/client-area-interface/#clientareaprimarynavbar) .
put your code in:

> WHMCS_ROOT\includes\hooks\MyPrimaryNavbar.php

This is a sample code:

```
<?php
    $ca = new WHMCS_ClientArea();
    use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;
    use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
add_hook('ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar', 1, function (MenuItem $primaryNavbar)
{
    global $CONFIG;
    $friendlyurl = $CONFIG['RouteUriPathMode'];
    if($friendlyurl == 'acceptpathinfo')
    {
        $urlpath = 'index.php/store/';

    }
    elseif($friendlyurl == 'rewrite')
    {
        $urlpath = 'store/';

    }
    elseif ($friendlyurl == 'basic')
    {
        $urlpath = 'index.php?rp=/store/';
    }
    $marketconnect = Capsule::table('tblmarketconnect_services')->where('status', '1')->get();
    $client = Menu::context('client');
    // Navbar Items for Clients
    if(!is_null($primaryNavbar->removeChild('Affiliates'))){}
    if(!is_null($primaryNavbar->removeChild('Open Ticket'))){}
    if(!is_null($primaryNavbar->removeChild('Store'))){}
    if(!is_null($primaryNavbar->removeChild('Website Security'))){}
    // Moved custom pages in services child menu 
    if(!is_null($primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')))
    {
        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->removeChild('Order New Services');
        if(count($marketconnect))
        {
            foreach ($marketconnect as $service)
            {
                if ($service->name == 'symantec')
                {
                    $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Manage SSL Certificates',array(
                                    'label' => Lang::trans('navManageSsl'),
                                    'uri' => $urlpath.'ssl-certificates/manage',
                                    'order' => '20',
                                ));
                }
            }
        }
        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Web Hosting', array(
                        'uri' => 'web-hosting.php',
                        'order' => '60',
                    ));
        #$primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Backup as a Service', array(
        #               'uri' => 'backup.php',
        #               'order' => '70',
        #           ));
        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Backup Service', array(
                        'uri' => 'backup-new.php',
                        'order' => '75',
                    ));
        #$primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Mail Hosting', array(
        #               'uri' => 'mail-hosting.php',
        #               'order' => '80',
        #           ));
        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Mail Hosting', array(
                        'uri' => 'mail-hosting-new.php',
                        'order' => '85',
                    ));
        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('E-Mail', array(
                        'uri' => 'mail.php',
                        'order' => '90',
                    ));
        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('DSGVO TOM Software', array(
                        'uri' => 'dsgvo.php',
                        'order' => '95',
                    ));
                    //$primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')
                    //  ->addChild('SSL Certificates', array(
                    //  'label' => Lang::trans('navMarketConnectService.symantec'),
                    //  'uri' => 'ssl-certificates.php',
                    //  'order' => '100',
                    //));

        if (count($marketconnect))
        {
            foreach ($marketconnect as $service)
            {
                if ($service->name == 'symantec')
                {
                    $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('SSL Certificates', array(
                                    'label' => Lang::trans('navMarketConnectService.symantec'),
                                    'uri' => $urlpath.'ssl-certificates',
                                    'order' => '100',
                                ));

                }
                elseif ($service->name == 'weebly')
                {
                    $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Website Builder', array(
                                    'label' => Lang::trans('navMarketConnectService.weebly'),
                                    'uri' => $urlpath.'website-builder',
                                    'order' => '110',
                                ));
                }
                if ($service->name == 'spamexperts')
                {
                    $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('E-mail Services', array(
                                    'label' => Lang::trans('navMarketConnectService.spamexperts'),
                                    'uri' => $urlpath.'email-services',
                                    'order' => '120',
                                ));
                }

            }
        }

    }
        //Moved Affiliate links to under Billing child menu 
        if(!is_null($primaryNavbar->getChild('Billing'))){

            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Billing')
                ->addChild('Affiliates', array(
                'label' => Lang::trans('affiliatestitle'),
                'uri' => 'affiliates.php',
                'order' => '70',
            ));
        }

        //Moved Open Ticket links to under Support child menu 
        if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->getChild('Support'))){
            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Support')->addChild('Open Ticket', array(
                'label' => Lang::trans('navopenticket'),
                'uri' => 'submitticket.php',
                'order' => '10',
            ));
            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Support')->addChild('Contact Us', array(
                'label' => Lang::trans('contactus'),
                'uri' => 'contact.php',
                'order' => '70',
            ));
        }
        // Custom About Us menu rearrange order for clients
        //if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->addChild('Über uns'))) {
        //  $navItem = $primaryNavbar->getChild('Über uns');
        //  if (is_null($navItem)) {
        //      return;
        //  } 

        //  $navItem->setOrder(40);
        //  $navItem->setUri('about-us.php');
        //}



    if(is_null($client))
    {
        // Navbar Items for visitors
        if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->removeChild('Announcements'))){}
        if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->removeChild('Network Status'))){}
        if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->removeChild('Knowledgebase'))){}
        // Custom Servers menu for logout clients
        if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->addChild('Services'))){
            $navItem = $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services');
            if (is_null($navItem)){
                return;
            }
            $navItem->setOrder(20);
            $navItem->setLabel(Lang::trans('navservices'));
            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Web Hosting', array(
                'uri' => 'web-hosting.php',
                'order' => '10',
            ));

            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Backup Service', array(
                'uri' => 'backup-new.php',
                'order' => '20',
            ));

            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Mail Hosting', array(
                'uri' => 'mail-hosting-new.php',
                'order' => '25',
            ));

            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('E-Mail Service', array(
                'uri' => 'mail-service.php',
                'order' => '30',
            ));

            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Software', array(
                'uri' => 'software.php',
                'order' => '40',
            ));

            //$primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')
            //  ->addChild('SSL Certificates', array(
            //  'label' => Lang::trans('navMarketConnectService.symantec'),
            //  'uri' => 'ssl-certificates.php',
            //  'order' => '50',
            //));

            if (count($marketconnect)){
                foreach ($marketconnect as $service) {
                    if ($service->name == 'symantec') {
                        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('SSL Certificates', array(
                            'label' => Lang::trans('navMarketConnectService.symantec'),
                            'uri' => $urlpath.'ssl-certificates',
                            'order' => '50',
                        ));

                    }
                    elseif ($service->name == 'weebly') {
                        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('Website Builder', array(
                            'label' => Lang::trans('navMarketConnectService.weebly'),
                            'uri' => $urlpath.'website-builder',
                            'order' => '60',
                        ));

                    }
                    if($service->name == 'spamexperts'){

                        $primaryNavbar->getChild('Services')->addChild('E-mail Services', array(
                            'label' => Lang::trans('navMarketConnectService.spamexperts'),
                            'uri' => $urlpath.'email-services',
                            'order' => '70',
                        ));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Custom support menu
        if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->addChild('Support'))) {
            $navItem = $primaryNavbar->getChild('Support');
            if(is_null($navItem)){
            return;
            }

            $navItem->setOrder(20);
            $navItem->setLabel(Lang::trans('navsupport'));

            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Support')->addChild('Tickets', array(
                'label' => Lang::trans('navtickets'),
                'uri' => 'supporttickets.php',
                'order' => '10',
            ));

            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Support')->addChild('Knowledgebase', array(
                'label' => Lang::trans('knowledgebasetitle'),
                'uri' => 'knowledgebase.php',
                'order' => '20',
            ));

            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Support')->addChild('Announcements', array(
                'label' => Lang::trans('announcementstitle'),
                'uri' => 'announcements.php',
                'order' => '30',
            ));

            $primaryNavbar->getChild('Support')->addChild('Network Status', array(
                'label' => Lang::trans('networkstatustitle'),
                'uri' => 'serverstatus.php',
                'order' => '40',
            ));
        }

        // Custom About Us menu rearrange order for visitors
        $navItem = $primaryNavbar->getChild('About us');
            if (is_null($navItem)){
                return;
            }
        $navItem->setOrder(30);
    }

});
?>
```